# If humans can be shrunk down to the quantum level, does this mean that the shrunk human will experience time slower as they have smaller mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, time-dilation, quantum-eraser

I am doing some research about "time travelling" by shrinking humans to the quantum level. It's something based on the delayed choice quantum experiment, so that we can go back to the past and travel to another parallel universe or to another universe in another timeline. So I just want to make sure if smaller mass changes the way the smaller object experiences time. But do note that I am only 16 so I do wish that it can be simple haha so that I don't end up being more confused.

Comment: This is a science fiction question, not a mainstream physics question that can be answered on this site.If you go on and study physics , and particularly special relativity, you will understand that mass is an ivariant characteristic of objects , including humans, .Also going to parallel universes is not within mainstream physics..In any case you need a course in special relativity to navigate these concepts. The mathematics is important., here is a course : https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-20-introduction-to-special-relativity-january-iap-2005/

Comment: Unrelated, but this reminds me of the time travel in "Avengers Endgame". Also, if you shrink something/somebody, they would still have the same mass, just more condensed. I think you could make this question more mainstream (and thus on-topic) if you focused more on the question "Does mass affect the perception/'passing' of time?" instead of the time travel part. You can [edit] your question if you want.

Comment: However: *Ex falso sequitur quodlibet*.  That is a reason for the existing plethora of amazing SciFi movies :)....

Answer (score 3):

> I am doing some research about "time travelling" by shrinking humans to the quantum level.

For educational purposes I will explain why this is impossible.

Atoms and molecules are the sizes they are because of quantum physics.  You cannot scale these up and down in the manner you want.  Effectively you would end up with every atom in the human body trying to share the same space, which is completely impossible without killing the human.  Humans only work if the atoms they are built from occupy the space they need.  Squish them and they usually don't keep functioning well (or at all).

Shrinking won't let you time travel.  You can't jump to other universes (if such a thing even exists) this way (and you'd be dead anyway by squishing).

The mass of humans is pretty much defined by the mass of the atoms they are made of.  Shrinking doesn't change that basic mass.  But if it did you'd end up with the human shrinking at the center of a *massive* nuclear explosion, because the only way to get rid of the mass is to convert it to massless particles - probably photons - which would incinerate everything for miles, including the shrinking human.  What you'd end up with is a vaporized human.

> I just want to make sure if smaller mass changes the way the smaller object experiences time

Smaller mass does not change how time passes.  Time passes at the same rate for an electron at rest as it does for a human at rest.