# Do objects with different sizes or masses experience time differently when they are moving in a constant velocity in their own reference frame?

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, atoms

My question is actually not about curve spacetime. Just curious if different mass affects how the object experiences time. Hope that someone can give a detailed explanation on this. Thank you!

Comment: This was answered earlier today, whereupon the OP promptly re-posted it:: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/635065/if-humans-can-be-shrunk-down-to-the-quantum-level-does-this-mean-that-the-shrun

Answer (score 0):

No not at all because in its own reference frame it will mesure the proper time only veiwing from a diffrent reference frame will you find any form of time dilation weather it is from the velocity or mass .